# Add a svg inside another svg

Tags: html, angular, svg

I have a circle svg which i want it to have a circle in the end of it.

The result is [image]

But what i want to do is, where the white point is supposed to be a white circle which follows progress
[image]

```
<svg
  attr.height="{{radius * 2}}"
  attr.width="{{radius * 2}}"
>
  <circle
    class="gauge_base"
    attr.cx="{{radius}}"
    attr.cy="{{radius}}"
    stroke="#aaaaaa"
    attr.r="{{innerRadius}}"
    stroke-width="6px"
    attr.transform="{{transform}}"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    fill="transparent"
    attr.stroke-dasharray="{{dashArray}}"
  />

  <circle
    class="gauge_pourcentage"
    attr.cx="{{radius}}"
    attr.cy="{{radius}}"
    attr.r="{{innerRadius}}"
    stroke="#01c495"
    attr.stroke-dasharray="{{dashArray}}"
    stroke-width="12px"
    attr.stroke-dashoffset="{{offset}}"
    attr.transform="{{transform}}"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    fill="transparent"
  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Whats your question, actually?

Comment: @somethinghere i want to add a white point inside my progress svg which is the second circle

Comment: In javascript you can use [getPointAtLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getPointAtLength) to get a point on a path at a given length. The length is the first value of the stroke-dasharray